# Downloading file using spring integration

Tags: java, xml, ftp, spring-integration

I have some issue when I try to download file from ftp server. 
Everything works perfectly when I try to save downloaded file to empty folder, but when folder contains any other file my code don't even connect to server. 
Here's my context file:

```
    <bean id="ftpClientFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="bufferSize" value="10000000"/>                  
</bean>
    <int:channel id="getFtpChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter local-directory="ftp/" 
            channel="getFtpChannel" 
            session-factory="ftpClientFactory" 
            remote-directory="./"
            auto-create-local-directory="false"
            delete-remote-files="true"
            filename-pattern="*.exi">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="10000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

And my java code:

```
public void receiveTest() {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
            new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/citrus/resources/citrus-context.xml");
    PollableChannel channel = context.getBean("getFtpChannel", PollableChannel.class);
    channel.receive(); 
    context.close();
}
```

Test passes and looks like everything works but it don't. 
Do you have some ideas what is wrong? 
Thanks for advance.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't download files from FTP, when your local dir `ftp/` isn't empty ? Try to show the DEBUG logs for `org.springframework.integration` category for that bad case.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. I'll try to get those logs and then I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in a test case?

We don't fetch from ftp if there are already local files, until those files are processed.

We had a similar question a few weeks ago, when a user's test case exited before it got to the point where we looked for remote files.

Add a sleep to the end of test to verify.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right. Do you say that files shouldn't be fetched from server if any other file already exist in local directory? But what when I want to, for example fetch all of file stored on ftp server and I don't want to process them?

Comment: Ok, after I added Thread.sleep(int time) everything works. Thanks a lot.